# donde se puede descargar php/php.exe xampp

Tags: php7, vscode, xampp

descargue el xampp pero no hallo el php/php.exe, por lo que genera mensaje cuando inicio el visual studio code, por favor me ayudan.

> { "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+", "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true, "php.validate.executablePath": "c:/php/php.exe", "window.zoomLevel": -1, "git.autofetch": true }

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Te pusiste a buscar en el propio buscador de Windows dónde está el archivo php.exe? Debés pensarlo al revés: no es "descargar", es buscar dónde está ese archivo y cambiar la configuración en VSCode para apuntar a la ruta del mismo. Por cierto: Visual Studio Code != Visual Studio.

Comment: Buscaste en la carpeta de PHP del XAMPP??